# named functions vs lambda reflexion

Tags: kotlin

I am still learning Kotlin and trying to understand its core principles. What I do not get is this:

```
fun x() : Int { return 10 }
val y : () -> Int = ::x
val z : () -> Int = { 10 }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(::x) 
    println(y)   
    println(z)    
}
```

we get the following output:

```
fun x(): kotlin.Int
fun x(): kotlin.Int
() -> kotlin.Int
```

My question is why the output is not the same (I believed these functions should be interchangeable, equivalent)? I think the type of all the functions should be `() -> Int`. Why do we keep the original name with the function signature (`fun x`) even though it is assigned to a different name (`y`)? Is there any language design principle which would require such difference in function signatures?

And a bonus question - why do we need to use the operator `::`. It does not compile without it. But why is this required by the language design? Would not `val y = x` work just fine and be much simpler?

Answer (score 1):

`fun x()` is an ordinary named function from procedural programming. `val y` is a property which holds a reference to `x`. `val z` is an anonymous functional from functional programming.

`::` is a 'function reference', a kind of bridge between procedural and functional programming.

By default, your functions should be `fun`. Lambda expressions (anonymous functions), on the other side, are intended to be passed to other functions as callbacks.

Comment: Yeah... I kind of understand what you said. But if functions are the 'first class citizens' in Kotlin, why do we need to distinguish between functional and procedural origin of the function? Do they have different properties? I think not - you can call them, you can assign to something and you can pass them as arguments. You can do the same to the both types - named functions and lambdas as well. So why the differentiation?

Comment: @V.K. every feature in every language is a kind of compromise. Anonymous functions are objects, they can be passed as arguments, and on JVM they are anonymous classes. They are subclasses of Any (actually, `java.lang.Object`) implementing functional interface, they have `hashCode`, `equals`, `toString` (and even more) methods, and they impact GC somehow. On the other hand, named functions are ordinary methods on JVM. There's less technical difference when compiled to JS, since all functions in JS are kinda anonymous. Inconsistent functions syntax is a price for performance and Java interop.

Answer (score 0):

**IF** you think from my point of view, I think you can understand it immediately.

- `x` just is an identifier not a variable, so you can't reference it directly.
- `fun x()` is a class which derived from `Function0`.
- the expression `::x` is the instance of the type of `fun x()`, this is called [function reference expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) in kotlin.

> Kotlin makes functions and properties first-class citizens in the language, and introspecting them.

sometimes function has it own class in kotlin like as java-8 lambda expression. but [function reference expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) can't used with the diff [receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver).

when calling an [inline function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) followed with a lambda, both the lambda & the function will be inlined at call-sites. but call with a non-inline [function reference expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references), only the [inline function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) will be inlined at call-sites.

Comment: `fun x()` is not a class, it's a method on JVM. `::x` is an anonymous class.

Comment: @Miha_x64 sir, I say it occurs in sometimes not always.

Answer (score 0):

I think for better understanding look at bytecode

```
  private final static Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0; y
  @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible

  // access flags 0x1A
  // signature Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0<Ljava/lang/Integer;>;
  // declaration: kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0<java.lang.Integer>
  private final static Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0; z
  @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible

  // access flags 0x19
  public final static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible, parameter 0
   L0
    ALOAD 0
    LDC "args"
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 6 L1
    GETSTATIC MainKt$main$1.INSTANCE : LMainKt$main$1;
    ASTORE 1
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   L2
    LINENUMBER 7 L2
    GETSTATIC MainKt.y : Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;
    ASTORE 1
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   L3
    LINENUMBER 8 L3
    GETSTATIC MainKt.z : Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;
    ASTORE 1
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   L4
    LINENUMBER 9 L4
    RETURN
   L5
    LOCALVARIABLE args [Ljava/lang/String; L0 L5 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 2

  // access flags 0x19
  public final static x()I
   L0
    LINENUMBER 11 L0
    BIPUSH 10
    IRETURN
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 0

  // access flags 0x19
  // signature ()Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0<Ljava/lang/Integer;>;
  // declaration: kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0<java.lang.Integer> getY()
  public final static getY()Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;
  @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible
   L0
    LINENUMBER 12 L0
    GETSTATIC MainKt.y : Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;
    ARETURN
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 0

  // access flags 0x19
  // signature ()Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0<Ljava/lang/Integer;>;
  // declaration: kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0<java.lang.Integer> getZ()
  public final static getZ()Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;
  @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible
   L0
    LINENUMBER 13 L0
    GETSTATIC MainKt.z : Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;
    ARETURN
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 0

  // access flags 0x8
  static <clinit>()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 12 L0
    GETSTATIC MainKt$y$1.INSTANCE : LMainKt$y$1;
    CHECKCAST kotlin/jvm/functions/Function0
    PUTSTATIC MainKt.y : Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;
   L1
    LINENUMBER 13 L1
    GETSTATIC MainKt$z$1.INSTANCE : LMainKt$z$1;
    CHECKCAST kotlin/jvm/functions/Function0
    PUTSTATIC MainKt.z : Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;
    RETURN
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 0
}
```

y and z value have type Function0

```
static <clinit>()V // here we have static initialization block where y and z are initialized
```

x have type MainKt$main$1

In each case(println) we just show method declaration(visibility modifiers, return type, signature) without invocation.
y and z are high order function that in bytecode are presented by Function0 class, for x value it's just static function.

And when you invoke `println(::x) println(y) println(z)` you just print functions declarations. This is ok, that declaration of x and y functions are different that in z function. Because y has reference to x function and z are still high order function that return 10. In simple words y == x, because you assign to y function declaration from x. 
Just for Note. In Java I can show method declaration in this way:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      System.out.println(Main.class.getMethod("A", null)); // prints public static void Main.A()
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void A() {
    System.out.println(15);
  }
```

Conclusion:
In your code you just print function return type, visibility modifier and signature.

Comment: I love answers that start.. "for a better understanding, let's look at a large pile of bytecode..."